# Using modules in views

Tags: web2py, web2py-modules

How can I use modules in views? 
For example I'm trying to use the `markdown` module, so I import it into my controller:

```
from gluon.contrib.markdown.markdown2 import markdown
```

and I use response.render

```
return response.render('default/main.html', locals())
```

but when I try to access it in a view,

```
{{=markdown(post.message)}}
```

I get an error saying that it is not defined:

```
<type 'exceptions.NameError'> name 'markdown' is not defined
```

How can I pass module to views? Is there an alternative to the `locals()` function to get it done?

On a side note, I can access `db` and `session` from my views, is this because they are imported in my `models`?

`Web2Py Version 1.99.7 (2012-03-04 22:12:08) stable`

**UPDATE:** Importing it in my model `db.py` seems to fix it. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for record.

It is not a good idea to use locals()

instead of passing locals to response.render, it is better to create a dictionary with the keys you want to be available for the view to be rendered.

You can also include a reference to markdown on that dictionary

```
from gluon.contrib.markdown.markdown2 import markdown
mydict = dict(markdown=markdown, anotherkey=anothervalue)
return response.render("path/to/view", mydict)
```

Dont try to extend locals() in to mydict, you will run in to problems if you try this.

Also you can just use the default web2py behavior

```
from gluon.contrib.markdown.markdown2 import markdown
response.view = "path/to/view"
return dict(markdown=markdown, anotherkey=anothervalue)
```

another option for you is to import markdown in a model file.